# QML Behaviour without "on" specified

Tags: qt, qml

According to [Animation documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html) in section "Default Animation as Behaviors", they say that

> There are several methods of assigning behavior animations to properties.

One of them is that we should be able to use `Behaviour` without `on property` but I don't succeed in having it working.

Here is my example code. I have a colored circle, and changing the color should trigger the ColorAnimation but it doesn't

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        width: 75; height: 75; radius: width
        id: ball
        color: "salmon"

        Behavior {
            ColorAnimation { target: ball; duration: 100 }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: timer.start()

    Timer{
        id: timer
        onTriggered: {ball.color = "blue" }
        interval: 1000
    }
}
```

If I add `on color`, it works. I also tried to add `property: "color"` into `ColorAnimation` definition but nothing happens.

Comment: It seems like it is a Documentation Page that tends to be erroneous. A quite similar mistake has been fixed, some time ago: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11599

Comment: The `Behavior` in your example does not make sense. It must be associate with some property but in your case it is not. What if an item has several "color" properties?  Why btw do you want it without "on" keyword?

Comment: Should file a bug against this doc file: `qtdeclarative/src/quick/doc/snippets/qml/animation.qml`

Comment: @folibis: Just because it is written like this in the documentation. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html - section: Default Animation as Behavior.

Comment: I don't get this either how am I supposed to use Behaviors without the on syntax? Bug is open since 13 :(

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the docs a bit more I do not think there is another way to specify the property for Behaviors in QML, even though the animation docs suggest so.

Behavior is a Property Modifier Type more specific a property value write interceptor. Currently Behavior is the only one, see:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Writing `Behavior` without the `on <property>` only defines a new `Behavior` component. To use it, it must be applied on a property. Code from [Qt 5 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html#targetProperty-prop):

```
// FadeBehavior.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
Behavior {
    ...
}
```

Then use that `Behavior`:

```
Text {
    FadeBehavior on text {}
}
```